# php session cookie too persistent

Tags: php, session-cookies

I'm using PHP sessions to store session cookies. here is the script, that sends HTTP headers to a python script, including the session_id:

```
<div id="header" class="grid_24">
  <?php
  ob_start();
  session_start();
  $UA = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  $REF = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $IP =   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $GUID = session_id();
  $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  //echo $UA;
  //echo $REF;
  //echo $IP;
  //echo $GUID;
  echo ("python ../header_sender.py -u '$UA' -r '$REF' -i '$IP' -c '$GUID' -p '$actual_link' 2>&1");
  echo exec("python /var/www/html/oscommerce-2.3.3.4/header_sender.py -u '$UA' -r '$REF' -i '$IP' -c '$GUID' -p '$actual_link' 2>&1");
  ob_end_flush();
  ?>
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the same session is there even when I open another browser. My understanding is that `session_start()` saves a session cookie that lives while the browser is open. How can I get the same session when opening with another browser (I'm opening firefox and seeing the same cookie from a chrome session..)?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the session with [session_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php). You have to do that on top of your page and before `session_start();`.

Comment: and that would make the session cookie act as a session cookie(die when the browser closes)?

Comment: The session Cookie is a normal Cookie with a specific name and the session id in it. So if you delete the cookie on close the session is closed and you get a new one.